# What (if anything) influences ammo drops?

Tags: destiny

Sometimes when playing I will go ages without finding a green ammo drop and then sometimes I get far more than I need dropping at the same time. Are ammo drops completely random or are they influenced by actions you take?

For example does what weapon type you use influence what ammo drops? Do precision kills make a difference? Does doing lots of damage in a short time make a difference? These are all things that I have sometimes anecdotally thought make a difference but its always hard to tell the difference between that and RNG...

And as a last addendum do you have to have even done damage for something for it to drop ammo for you (eg if your fireteam kill it without you)...

Comment: I think it's all chance. Like its a 50% chance it will drop, then a 70% chance it's primary, 50% secondary and 30% heavy. Not providing this as an answer because my numbers are just speculation

Answer (score 3):

*I'll convert my comment to an answer as it was getting long.*

I get the feeling playing the game that precision kills drop more ammo, but have no evidence.

Do be aware some guns have the 'surplus' attribute which means more ammo will be found for that weapon slot.

[image: Surplus attribute]

Thanks to @Havatra for the thought. There might indeed be Grimoire cards for this. Here is an example of an area bonus earned through killing enemies in that area. So far I have seen bonuses to, `EXP`, `Weapon EXP` and `Materials`, but I don't have a huge Grimoire score and http://destiny-grimoire.info/ doesn't have the card bonuses listed.

[image: Back of card]

Comment: I think (I'm not certain) there are some Grimoire Cards that give bonus drop chance. But if this affects ammo drops or equipment drops, or both, I do not know.

Comment: Probably worth noting that there is a 'Juggler' mission modifier, which stops you receiving the ammo type of the currently equipped weapon. (I've only seen these on the heroic daily/weekly missions so far).

Comment: Post Loot Cave patch the drop system has been modified in an unspecified way, so it may no longer default to completely random drops.

Comment: @Eben: I thought the loot cave patch just changed the spawning rules. And then there is the cryptarch patch that will change engrams. I didn't see anything else about the drop system changing. You got a link I can read?

Comment: Both spawn changes (although maybe only in localized areas) and drop changes for full party wipes in the [dev notes](http://www.bungie.net/7_Destiny-Dev-Notes/en/News/News?aid=12188). I do see however that in the Hotfix 5 notes the only drops they changed were specifically for full party wipes.